# Add Numbers Together From Mysql Database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need to add some numbers together that are being pulled from a MySQL table to get a total value.

Currently the issue I have is the numbers being added to the end of a string instead.

e.g:

> 1,2,3,4 becomes 1234 instead of 10

Here is what I am using to get the numbers from the database:

```
$count = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT QUANTITY FROM Table");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count)) {
    $total .= $row['Quantity'];
    //I Have also tried
    $total .= (int)$row['Quantity'];
}

echo $total;
```

The Quantity Column is set to be an INT in the table so I would have expected it to add together automatically. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you used a dot instead of a plus `+` sign.

Comment: this is a typo question

Comment: Why not do `SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY FROM Table` as your database query?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I tried that and it gave the error Undefined Variable $total. I've now realised I should have created the variable initially as 0. So it works, thanks.

Comment: you could have first assigned it as `$total = "";` then the rest with the plus sign ;-) that is but one way to do it. That's why you got the undefined notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably look at the difference between `.=` and `+=`

By adding a `.` in front of `=` you concatenate - You add the value ad the end of the variable.

If you would use a `+` in front of your `=` you would actually get the result you want.

```
$count = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT QUANTITY FROM Table");
$total = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count)) {
    $total += $row['Quantity'];
}
echo $total;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php